# award phoenix bios not recognizing my sata hdd

Tags: hard-drive, troubleshooting, bios, sata

What am I doing wrong?

I have a custom built comp with a Fatal1ty AA8XE mobo. It has 4 SATA ports and one IDE port.

When i first got it, I had a really hard time putting in more than one hard drive. Right now i have one 120gb IDE HDD on master and my DVD+-RW on slave connected to the one IDE spot on the mobo.

I ripped a bunch of movies and filled up my HDD, so I got a WD 80gb SATA drive. I plugged it into SATA1 and hooked up the power, turned on comp, went into bios. The only thing in any option in any of the menues in this crazy lookin bios is a thing that says "SATA mode". i put it on IDE, set it so PATA is primary, SATA is secondary. booted up my comp, nothin. Not recognizing the SATA.

I went back into the bios and checked it all again. I saw that it says SATA2 and SATA4 are the secondaries so i put it on SATA2, booted, nothing, same with SATA4, same with SATA3, all same as SATA1.  Bios and wt os are not recognizing the drive as being there at all. I even downloaded and printed the almost 100 page manual for the mobo, read the entire thing, and still can't figure it out.

I know there are a lot of people out there smarter than me when it comes to computers.  So please, somebody, anybody, please tell me something that I'm not seeing. Some setting somewhere that I didn't configure right. There is something, obviously, but I can't find it. As far as i can tell, everything is set perfectly fine for my 120gb to be the master and the SATA to be the slave.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I'm seriously about to throw this computer out the window.

thankyou in advance to whoever attempts to help.

Comment: I highly recommend opening the window before any defenestration attempt.  Broken glass sucks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that you need to do to at least get to a working playing field.  so heres the basics,  DO you have the LATEST bios?  what version of windows are you using. So your primary is the ide with a sata as your secondary(which can't be seen)
have you tried to have the sata as your primary?(if it works with the sata being the primary then you might want to burn your data onto a dvd or USB then when the amount on the ide hardrive is alil LESS then the WD 80 gig then use a cloning program (ghost) to copy your disk bit for bit to the new hard drive)have you change bios to RECONIZE the hard drive in all the areas you can, even the boot options(it still may not see the drive untill you tell it to) lastly is the sata drivers installed for the motherbord?  all of these need to be addressed before any advanced troubleshooting can be done.